# How to delete multiple db entities with Nhibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hibernate, batch-file, batch-processing

What is the best practice for this problem? Is there any batching features built-in?

Sample code:

```
using (ITransaction transaction = _session.BeginTransaction())
{
   _session.Delete("FROM myObject o WHERE  o.Id = IN(1,2,...99999)");
   transaction.Commit();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

HQL supports the IN clause, and if you use setParameterList you can even pass in a collection.

```
var idList = new List<int>() { 5,3,6,7 };

_session.CreateQuery("DELETE MyDataClass o WHERE o.Id IN (:idList)")
    .SetParameterList("idList", idList)
    .ExecuteUpdate();
```

Be aware, like mentioned by ddango in a comment, that relationship cascades specified in your objects will not be executed since running an HQL query simply translates to a DB query and does not actually load any entity objects.

Comment: What if the idList is huge? How would you batch around it? or does nhibernate have some form of built-in batching?

Comment: I'd have to setup a test using nHibernate profiler [nhprof.com] to see what actually gets emitted to the DB, but if I had to guess I would say that it would look explicitly like your hard-coded example.

Comment: You can set a batch size in your <hibernate-configuration><session-factory>: <property name="adonet.batch_size">100</property>. However, based on your HQL, I would guess its just one query emitted (batches would apply if you were looping through a collection and calling Delete on them).

Answer (score 10):

I had problems getting the answer to work and I found the following query worked 100%

```
        Session.CreateQuery("delete Customer c where c.id in (:deleteIds)")
            .SetParameterList("deleteIds", deleteIds)
            .ExecuteUpdate();
```

Customer is the class name not the table name.
id is lowercase and in HQL it is the Primary Key not a property name in the class (Property names are supported)

Comment: Yep, and the only caveat that might be worth mentioning is that cascading is not going to be applied since you're not loading the object. So if Customer had an Address row attached and it normally cascade-deletes, this isn't going to honor that

Answer (score 5):

you can Use HQL to delete multiple objects

[Look for delete here - for session.delete example](http://nhibernate.sourceforge.net/NHibernateEg/NHibernateEg.Tutorial1A.html#NHibernateEg.Tutorial1A-CRUD.Delete)

HQL DELETE example (you can use IN with HQL):

```
ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction();

String hqlDelete = "delete Customer c where c.name = :oldName";
// or String hqlDelete = "delete Customer where name = :oldName";
int deletedEntities = session.CreateQuery( hqlDelete )
        .SetString( "oldName", oldName )
        .ExecuteUpdate();
tx.Commit();
session.Close();
```