# How to run an NHibernate SQL Delete with a final SELECT reporting completion?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, sql-delete

**Description**
For a project I'm working on, I'm creating a purge feature that deletes old data from this system's database.

I've found that, while my SQL works correctly when ran from SQL Studio, it does not work when ran from C# code.  Based on [some StackOverflow research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869057/how-to-delete-multiple-db-entities-with-nhibernate), I believe it's due to my needing to call `.ExecuteUpdate()`, instead of `.UniqueResult<PurgeResult>()` to actually fire the SQL statement.  *However,* my query is returning a `PurgeResult` based on if the DELETE statements throw any errors in SQL, so that developers can be informed if something goes wrong.

**C# NHibernate Code:**

```
public class PurgeResult {
    public int ResultCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public bool IsSuccessful => ResultCode == 1;
}

public static PurgeResult Purge(DateTime purgeTo)
{
    // Verified that my purge SQL runs in SQL studio.  It only fails
    // to delete anything when ran from my C# code.
    var sql = @"BEGIN TRY
                  TRANSACTION PurgeMySystem
                    DELETE FROM InsertTableHere
                      WHERE CreateDate <= :PurgeTo
                    -- Repeat deletes as necessary, specific delete statements may not be
                    -- relevant to this technical question.
                  COMMIT TRANSACTION PurgeMySystem

                  SELECT 1 AS ResultCode, 'Purge successful!' AS Message
                END TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                  BEGIN
                    ROLLBACK
                  END

                  SELECT 0 AS ResultCode,
                         CONCAT('Message: ', ERROR_MESSAGE(), '\r\n\r\n', 'At line: ', ERROR_LINE()) AS Message
                END CATCH";

    using (var session = DatabaseService.CreateSession())
    {
        var query = session.CreateSQLQuery(sql)
            .SetParameter("PurgeTo", purgeTo)
            .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(PurgeResult));

        // Problem line below!  I think for DELETE statements to work,
        // I need to run query.ExecuteUpdate(), but that only returns an
        // int representing row count affected by the statement.
        var result = query.UniqueResult<PurgeResult>();
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Question:**
Given a hybrid script above that both DELETEs records and returns a status of that effort, is there a way I can effectively run a script like this in NHibernate?  If so, what's the correct way to do what I'm trying to do?

*Alternatively:* Is there a way to specify what would effectively be an `out` parameter to this query, so I could still `.ExecuteUpdate()`, and have my result too?  In my normal programming, I try to avoid this, but a `bool TryDoSomething(out SomeObject resultObject)` pattern in C# isn't unknown, and this situation could well call for something like that setup.

Answer (score 0):

After some additional research, as well as conferring with colleagues, there's a simple **solution** to this problem: *Tailor your queries to do a specific thing, and don't be afraid to let C# handle things like error handling/reporting, and transactional setup.*

Put differently, this was a design problem.  The source SQL was from a stored proc.  While stored procs are useful in certain contexts, they have a problem: maintainability.  Not only are they separate from your application's codebase (not necessarily a problem), they'll typically do a lot in one compact package.  That's not very Single-Responsibility Principle-y at all.

NHibernate has an built-in bias towards keeping database actions focused.  As a result, it doesn't support output parameters or returning a complex result from a set of update queries.  The good news, though, is that some of the structures one may see in SQL lifted from a legacy proc - like, Try/Catch structures, creating, committing, and rolling back transactions, and reporting status based on if the Catch of a Try/Catch structure is hit - are all quite doable by modern programming languages.

So, do those things in modern programming languages.  End result is the above code can be simplified somewhat...

```
public static PurgeResult Purge(DateTime purgeTo)
{
    PurgeResult result;

    var sql = @"DELETE FROM InsertTableHere
                    WHERE CreateDate <= :PurgeTo
                -- Repeat deletes as necessary, it's cool!";

    using (var session = DatabaseService.CreateSession())
    using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try {
            var query = session.CreateSQLQuery(sql)
                .SetParameter("PurgeTo", purgeTo);

            int purgeRowCount = query.ExecuteUpdate();
            transaction.Commit();

            result = PurgeResult.Success($"Purge complete.  Deleted {purgeRowCount} rows of data across various tables.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            result = PurgeResult.Exception(ex);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```